# Create an object of nested class in templated class

Tags: c++, c++11

I am struggling with this, and would appreciate some help!

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

enum Enum{A, B, C};

template<class T>
class classA
{
    public:

    template<Enum E = A>
    class innerClassA
    {
        public:
        innerClassA() {}
    };
};

template<class T>
class classB
{
    public:
    classB(){}

    template<Enum E = A>
    void foo() 
    {
        // using innerClassA= typename classA<T>::template innerClassA;
        // innerClassA <T, S> mult; // Not working
        typename classA<T>::innerClassA myInnerClassA; // Not working
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    classB<int> obj2;
    obj2.foo();

   return 0;
}
```

I would like to create an object of `innerClassA` inside the function foo. But unfortunately, I am not able to do it.
Can someone give me a hand?

Best  wishes !

Answer (score 3):

`innerClassA` is a template *not* a type, you need to specify the template parameter explicitly

```
typename classA<T>::template innerClassA<E> myInnerClassA;
                 //^^^^^^^^^            ^^^
```

Comment: That will give me: `error: non-template ‘innerClassA’ used as template
   29 |         typename classA<T>::innerClassA<E> myInnerClassA;`

Comment: I'm guessing you are using a gcc version below 10. updated.